# How to change django-leaflet settings inside Selenium Tests

Tags: python, django, selenium, leaflet

I need to write a Selenium test to draw a polygon on a map. For that I need to change the [NO_GLOBALS](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet/tree/d3d204eeffef73ebd38d164abe922cbd5fdc66eb#global-initialization-functions-and-windowmaps) setting.

How to do that inside a python selenium test?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're running your tests via Django. If so, you could apply [`override_settings` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) or create separate settings for test, change `NO_GLOBAL` variable there and then run your tests with `--settings` flag